# Regex to match the number zero

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I need a regex which will match decimal forms of the number zero such as 0 or 0.0 or 0.00000 but not multiples of 10 such as 110.0000

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324961/regex-to-match-for-zeros) SO question and it doesn't really match.

I've been using the great online regex tool [here](http://regexr.com/) to test patterns but I've had limited success.

The best I could think of was `(\b0+(\.)?0+\b)` Unfortunately regex sees `.` as a word boundary so it ends up capturing the `.000` in `25.000` for example. Dropping my `?` fixes that problem but then misses any isolated single `0` characters

Comment: Knowing which dialect of regexp you are using has impact on this answer. Just in case, you should always tag with a regexp dialect (you never know when it's relevant)

Comment: I'm using the regex built into python 2.7 if that helps. I'm not sure about "dialects" or how to determine them or apply them on the testing site.

Comment: Tagging with "[tag:regex] [tag:python]" is good enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?<!\.)\b0(?:\.0+)?(?!\.)\b
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cZ0sD2/13

Comment: Hey! regex101 is nice.

Answer (score 3):

```
(?<![\d.])0+(?:\.0+)?(?![\d.])
```

There is not a digit or a decimal point preceding; then any number of zeroes, optionally followed by a decimal point and any number of zeroes; and there is not a digit or a decimal point following.

However, this will not work in engines without lookbehind, like JavaScript's.

Comment: misses `0.` It's not a deal breaker just a comment.

Comment: @MrPurple: I was not under impression that it is a pattern to look for, given the question. But indeed, it does not match `0.`.

Comment: +1 as this worked for me and I appreciated the explanation. Note also that it does capture `00` which is ok for me but perhaps not others.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?:^|[ ])0+(?:\.0+)?(?:[ ]|$)
```

If you have a need to retrieve the exact text of zero, just wrap it in parens and you can match it out. Add any other characters you want to the braces or replace by a class such as `\s` or `[:[space]:]` (or however it's represented in your language)

Comment: Doesn't match " 0. " nor " .0 ", are those forms significant?

Comment: If he wants those things, just change the inside to `(0+(?:\.0*)?|\.0+)`

Answer (score 0):

This pattern got ugly fast:

```
(?:^|[^.\d])(0?\.0+|0)(?:[^.\d]|$)
```

`(?:^|[^.\d])` non matching group of anything that's not a digit nor a period but can be the start of a line

`(0?\.0+|0)`  matching group to match either float or integer zero

`(?:[^.\d]|$)` non matching group of anything that's not a digit nor a period but can be the end of a line

Should handle the obvious cases, even on a line by themselves.  Should handle zero in context, e.g. "0.0in" or a coordinate "(34.8,0.0)"  Currently screws up on "0."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can helps:

On the regex tool site that you point, this expression:

```
((!(\d+0\.0*))|(\d*[^0]\.0*)|([^\d]0\.0)|([^\d]0\.)|(^0))
```

Explanation:

```
!(\d+0\.0*)    => does not match digits ends with 0 following by a dot and zeros
(\d*[^0]\.0*)  => match digits that not have a zero before the dot, following by zeros
([^\d]0\.0)    => match 0.0 that having no digits before the first zero
([^\d]0\.)     => match 0. that having no digits before the first zero
(^0)           => math a zero on the starts of the line
```

Results in:

```
0              <- match
0.0            <- match
25.00000       <- match
10.00000       <- does not match
110.0000       <- does not match
2818.0000      <- match
120901821.000  <- match
0.             <- match
```